# How to get localStorage to work on a todolist-app

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

I have no clue how localStorage works and I need it for my project. I'm doing a todolist-app and I need to save the items so the user can turn off the app and that the list is still there when they open the app again. How do I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest = offline.appcache>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">  
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


<title>Inköpslista</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="kol1" class="kol">

    <h1>Inköp</h1>
    <input type="image" src="img/button.png" alt="Submit" id="storknapp"     onclick="klickaKnapp('skriva')"/>
        <div id="form">
        <input type"text" id="skriva" placeholder="Skriv din vara här!"/>
        <input type="image" id="knapp" src="img/pluss.png" alt="Submit"/>
        </div>   


</div>

<div id="kol2">
<ul id="listaavvara"></ul>
</div>



</body>
<script src="menudropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you search? This is the first result on google http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @adrianogalessoalves yeah, i did but didn't understand it.

Comment: Do you know JavaScript?

Comment: @adrianogalessoalves a bit, this's my first course that ends in december

Comment: I tried to answer, but you need to test there

Answer (score 0):

Cookies slow down you web application, so if you to store data into the client browser you might want to use localStorage or sessionStorage. So if you want:

- a lot of storage space
- on the client
- that persists beyond a page refresh
- and isn’t transmitted to the server

Create a value:

```
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```

Get the value:

```
var foo = localStorage["bar"];
```

Remove values:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

If you want to create a list, for instance, you can store a JSON value into the localStorage like:

```
localStorage.setItem("list", "[{"name":"Adriano"},{"name":"Vic"},{"name":"Test"}]");
```

Then you retrieve it and assemble in your page with JS.

This link is PERFECT: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

By the way: It doesn't have expiration date like cookies =)

Comment: but we need unique id for everything we put in the input-field, do u have an answer for that?

Comment: and how do i then get my unique id in to this code :)